# how to string contacate with mutiple variable and create a tag in php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create a tag with contact. but, it does not working for me. 
here is the required output, that i want.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction('1','0','Unpaid','tr_1','td_1')">Link</a>
```

i want this type of a tag using php code

```
<?php
$id="1";
$status = "unpaid";
$str = "0";
$trid = "tr_1";
$tdid = "td_1";

echo $a = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction({$id})" class="btn btn-sucess">link</a>';
?>
```

Comment: what's the problem thats happening ?

Comment: `echo $a = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction({$id},{$str},{$status},{$trid},{$tdid})" class="btn btn-sucess">link</a>';` ?

Comment: your out put this <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunction({$id},{$str},{$status},{$trid},{$tdid})" class="btn btn-sucess">link</a> i want this <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myfunction('1','0','Unpaid','tr_1','td_1')">Link</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use outer double quotes, and escape inner double quotes.

```
<?php
$id="1";
$status = "unpaid";
$str = "0";
$trid = "tr_1";
$tdid = "td_1";

echo $a = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"myfunction({$id})\" class=\"btn btn-sucess\">link</a>";
?>
```

PHP doesn't interpret variables in single quotes.